# Watertight connector for Honeywell genesis 10753908

Tags: electrical, mini-split

I have some Honeywell Genesis 10753908 cable that I need to connect to a mini split outdoor unit.  The thing is outdoors, so it should be a wet and UV rated connector.  Unfortunately, I have been having trouble finding the correct item.  Does anyone know what you use to connect this to a 1/2 knock out?

The wire is 14/4 with aluminum armor, and the aluminum armor is coated with what looks like black rubber (I think it may be some kind of PVC but I'm not certain).

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=outdoor+electrical+box&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: That image search is for outdoor electrical boxes, not the connectors used to transition from the wire into an electrical box.